# Cycling With Diabetes

Tags: compatibility

I am 40 Years Old. I got diabetes at the age of 21. In that case how long can I cycling per day. Am I Compatible for long ride. Which type of bike and roads are compatible for me.

Comment: Without more medical data, one that you should *not* share with us, we can't tell. With diabetes you should have a medical professional looking out for you. Next visit you just ask your doctor.

Comment: Sorry - we can't comment on medical things .  Instead you should consult a qualified medical person.  Your main challenge will be around food and fuelling and pacing.  The type of bike, and what roads/tracks you ride will not really matter.

Comment: I have done week-long, 70-mile-per-day group rides that included people with type 1 diabetes.  It's a matter of knowing how to manage your blood sugar levels.  Should be easier now with CGMs, etc.  The bike has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Like Daniel, I also have friends who cycle with diabetes, and not short distances.  The While the medical aspect is between you and your doctor, the usual advice of starting gently and building up as you find what you're capable of and what you enjoy is still applicable - if anything it's more important as you'll have to be more careful to manage your condition (which is likely to involve carrying more than many people on short rides).  Good luck to you, and don't be put off by this question being closed, it's just that we're not in a position to help you very much.

Comment: There is actually a pro cycling team that only recruits riders with diabetes.  You might be able to find some good info and inspiration there: https://www.teamnovonordisk.com